# Algorithm to determine the global minima of a blackbox function

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, gradient-descent

I recently got this question in an interview, and it's kind of making me mad thinking about it.

Suppose you have a family of functions that each take a fixed number of parameters (different functions can take different numbers of parameters), each with the following properties:

1. Each input is between 0-1
2. Each output is between 0-1
3. The function is continuous
4. The function is a blackbox (i.e you cannot look at the equation for it)

He then asked me to create an algorithm to find the global minima of this function.

To me, looking at this question was like trying to answer the basis of machine learning. Obviously if there was some way to guarantee to find the global minima of a function, then we'd have perfect machine learning algorithms. Obviously we don't, so this question seems kind of impossible.

Anyways, the answer I gave was a mixture of divide and conquer with stochastic gradient descent.  Since all functions are continuous, you'll always be able to calculate the partial gradient with respect to a certain dimension. You split each dimension in half and once you've reached a certain granularity, you apply stochastic gradient descent. In gradient descent, you initialize a certain start point, and evaluate the left and right side of that point based on a small delta with respect to every dimension to get the slope at that point. Then you update your point based on a certain learning rate and recalculate your partial derivatives until you've reached a point where the distance between old and new point is below a certain threshold. Then you re-merge and return the minimum of the two sections until you return the minimum value from all your divisions. My hope was to get around the fact that SGD can get stuck in local minima, so I thought dividing the dimension space would reduce the chance of that happening.

He seemed pretty unimpressed with my algorithm in the end. Does anybody have a faster/more accurate way of solving this problem?

Comment: I don't think "continuous" means anything if all you have is a discrete set of machine floating-point numbers. You need to know the possible range of the derivatives. If you know it, the solution becomes possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The range is `[0, 1]`, therefore `f(x) = 0`, where `x` on `R^n`, is the global minima. Moreover, it's not guaranteed that the function will be a convex, by knowing the domain, range, and continuity holds.

**ex.** `f(x) = sqrt(x)`, it's a concave function (**i.e.** has no minimum), and `x - [0, 1]` belongs to its domain.